# Could we write a browser extension with which we could get control to addressbar without using any hotkeys?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Could we write a browser extension with which we could get control to addressbar without using any hotkeys? 
Currently chrome has omnibox api which allows to register a keyword. User has enter the keyword first then every keystroke is sent to extension. Could the samething be achieved without any keyword?

Comment: You can use webRequest.onBeforeRequest to intercept requests to the default search engine made by browser when user types in the address bar, then extract `q=` URL parameter, for example.

Comment: this gives me a hacky way to capture userstrokes , but i am actually looking for rightway if it exists. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Extensions don't have an API you want. Firefox *addons* may have but that's a completely different beast, not to be confused with WebExtensions.